# SCHEME: Objects in a list

Tags: list, object, scheme

I have a list of objects in scheme as described below. How is it possible to call objects functions when for example taking the first element out of the list?

```
(define persons false)
(define length 10)

(let loop ((n 0))
    (if (< n length)
        (begin
            (define newp (make-person))
            (send newp setage (- 50 n))

            (cond
                 ((= n 0)
                        (set! persons (list newp)))
                 (else
                        (set! persons (cons persons newp)))
            )

            (loop (+ n 1))
        )
     )
 )

 (define (firstpersonage)
     (send (car persons) getage)
 )
```

When calling the firstpersonage I am getting error message that there is no such method. Is there way to "cast" the first object to be "person" type?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the implementation of the `make-person` procedure?

Comment: Consider replacing your use of `let loop` and `set!` with a `map` over the numbers 0..9 (can be generated with `(iota 10)`).  I know this is not what you asked, but I think it will make your code shorter and more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please [do](http://dept-info.labri.fr/~idurand/enseignement/lst-info/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html) learn to [indent](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/proglang/scheme/indentation.html) Lisp correctly.

Second, your problem is that you've decided to use a pile of side effects to construct a list of people in Scheme (and as a consequence, you tripped over one of the finer points of
list construction).

What I would do in this situation is write

```
(define persons
  (map (lambda (n)
         (let ((newp (make-person)))
           (send newp setage (- 50 n))
           newp))
       (iota 10)))

(define (firstpersonage)
  (send (car persons) getage))
```

That is, define `person` to be the list of ten people of descending ages from 50 to 41. Doing it this way avoids the possibility for many bugs, including the one you just got bitten by.

If you absolutely, positively can't bear to part with your `set!`s, the error seems to be in the line

```
(set! persons (cons persons newp))
```

`cons` doesn't append two lists, it adds a new element to the head of a list. For example

```
(cons 3 (list 2 1)) => (3 2 1)
```

If you do it in the reverse way, you won't quite get what you're looking for

```
(cons (list 1 2) 3) => ((1 2) . 3)
```

Comment: In Scheme you should use map rather than mapcar, no?

Comment: @Jonas - Dammit, you're right. I'm a Common Lisper in real life, so forgive the slip.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you're using `cons` the wrong way; you're not constructing a proper list. `(cons persons newp)` creates a new pair and puts persons in the `car` and `newp` in the `cdr`, so when you're done, what's in the `car` of `persons` is not one of those person-objects. You might find that `(cdr persons)` is a person-object though, and that you can do `(send (cdr persons) getage)` just fine. And `(cdar persons)` and `(cdaar persons)`are person-objects too. So it *kind of* is a list, only the items are in the `cdr`s and the tails are in the `car`s (until you get to the initial list that you created with `(list newp)` where it's the other way around again).

Anyway, if you switch it around so it goes `(cons newp persons)` it should work.